# PickerView didSelectRow does not show the correct values

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I have created a simple weather application app which shows the temperature in different cities.

I have created a `UIpickerview` with about 10 cities.

Also, i have implemented a `UISwitch` so that user can switch between Fahrenheit or Celsius.

But i got stuck on one problem, when i scroll through the cities, it shows me the incorrect temperature values, but if i switch between Fahrenheit and Celsius it shows me the correct results.

Also, for example

City1
City2

The app shows me the same results for city1 and city2.

here is my function for scrolling through the cities  and i suppose that i have done something wrong with it. Maybe i forgot to add some update feature

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    row = [self.PickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [theWeather getCurrent:_pickerData[row]];

        if (self.SwitchOutlet.on){
            self.LabelForSwitch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:

                                        @"Temperature in Fahrenheit is .: %2.1f \n",
                                        theWeather.tempCurrentInF
                                        ];

        }
        else
        {
            self.LabelForSwitch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"Temperature in Celsius is.: %2.1f \n",
                                        theWeather.tempCurrent
                                        ];

        }


    self.indicator.hidden = YES;


}
```

and here is my function for Switch between Fahrenheit and Celsius

```
- (IBAction)Switch:(id)sender {
    if (self.SwitchOutlet.on){
        self.LabelForSwitch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:

                                    @"Temperature in Fahrenheit is .: %2.1f \n",
                                    theWeather.tempCurrentInF
                                    ];

    }
    else
    {
        self.LabelForSwitch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Temperature in Celsius is.: %2.1f \n",
                                    theWeather.tempCurrent
                                    ];

    }

}
```

if you need me to clarify something, please say so

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i needed to create a delay for my Uipickerview. It just didnt have enough time to load data from the server.